# What are these Bytes in the OID returned by X509Certificte.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32")?

Tags: x509certificate, x509

I am pulling the `2.5.29.32` Certificate Policy OID bytes from an X.509 certificate. I am not using BouncyCastle.

```
bytes = _cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32");
```

The raw bytes I get are

```
4, 15, 48, 13, 48, 11, 6, 9, 96, -122, 72, 1, 101, 2, 1, 11, 42
```

After DER decode (type = 4, size = 15), I have:

```
48, 13, 48, 11, 6, 9, 96, -122, 72, 1, 101, 2, 1, 11, 42
```

What I am after is the:

```
96, -122, 72, 1, 101, 2, 1, 11, 42 (2.16.840.1.101.2.1.11.42)
```

What are the bytes: `48, 13, 48, 11, 6, 9`?

Comment: These bytes are `Policy Identifier` OID value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`48` (aka `0x30`) is the tag for CONSTRUCTED SEQUENCE (all SEQUENCE values are CONSTRUCTED, but still).

The 13 is the length value, as is the 11 two bytes later.

`6` (aka `0x06`) is the tag for OBJECT IDENTIFIER (aka OID), and 9 is its length.

So `30 0D 30 0B 06 09 ...` is `SEQUENCE(SEQUENCE(OID(... [ 9 bytes ])))`.

- ITU-T [X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.680-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items)-201508, the ASN.1 language.
- ITU-T [X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items)-201508, the BER (and CER) and DER encodings for ASN.1 data.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested in the code I wrote to do this...

```
private static byte CONSTRUCTED_SEQUENCE_TAG = 48;
private static byte OID_CODE = 6;

private static String extractPolicyOid(X509Certificate pCert) throws IOException {

    byte[] _bytes = pCert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32");
    if (_bytes == null) {
        return null;
    }

    DerValue _der = new DerValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(_bytes));
    _bytes = _der.getOctetString();

    /*
     * Skip header goo
     */
    int _idx = 0;
    while (_idx < _bytes.length) {
        if (_bytes[_idx] == CONSTRUCTED_SEQUENCE_TAG) {
            _idx += 2;
        } else if (_bytes[_idx] == OID_CODE) {
            _idx += 2;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Create string version of OID
     */
    StringBuffer _sb = new StringBuffer();
    byte _byte = _bytes[_idx++];
    _sb.append(_byte / 40);
    _sb.append(".");
    _sb.append(_byte % 40);

    int _accum = 0;
    for (; _idx < _bytes.length; _idx++) {

        _byte = _bytes[_idx];

        if (_byte << ~7 < 0) {
            _accum = (_byte & 0x7f) << 7;
        } else {
            _accum += _byte;

            _sb.append(".");
            _sb.append(_accum);

            _accum = 0;
        }
    }

    return _sb.toString();

}
```